# newline characters screwing up <pre> tags (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, newline

I developing a blog and some really annoying stuff is happening with newline characters (\n). Everything works fine except if I make a post that contains pre tags my newline characters screw up the indentation.

So if I have code that looks like this

```
<pre>
  <code>
    some code some code
    more code more code
  </code>
</pre>
```

For some reason the newline characters that are saved in the db field with the post are causing whatever is inside the pre tag to be indented by a tab or two.

I have no idea why it's doing it, but if I do something like

```
string.gsub!(/\n/, "<br />")
```

The indentation is removed, so I know it has to do with the \n. But then my problem is that there are way too many line breaks and the format is then way off.

So then I tried to capture everything inside the pre tags with a method that looks like this

```
def remove_newlines(string)
   regexp = /<pre>\s?(.*?)\s?<\/pre>/
   code = regexp.match(string)
   code[1].gsub!(/\n/, "<br />")
end
```

But I can't get that to work properly.

Anyone know how I can rid of this weird indentation problem, or any pointers on this?

Thanks!

Comment: it'll be raw text like this:

"My post\r\n<pre>\r\n<code>\r\nsome text some text\r\n\r\nsome more text more text</code>\r\n</pre>\r\n"

Comment: @Rhinoo, "it'll be raw text like this...". No, please add some samples of the text to your question. You can wrap it in `<pre>...`</pre>` tags to keep the formatting, or modify it a bit to show leading and trailing spaces and carriage returns and line-feeds.

Comment: stripping out \r doesn't do anything, stripping out \n did though. 

@the Tin Man, I could copy and paste code from the DB, but it's just being built right now, i have no real records, just fake ones that look exactly like what i said in the comment above.

@mu they certainly appear to be tabs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like your template engine is auto-indenting the contents of the `<pre>` tags. Browsers render the whitespace inside `<pre>` tags as it is (and so they should, according to specs). This means that the whitespace at the beginning of each line inside the `<pre>` added by the template engine in order to make the HTML source more readable is rendered in the actual page as well, unlike whitespace most other places in HTML source.

The solution therefore depends on your templating language.

If you are using HAML:

[HAML FAQ: How do I stop Haml from indenting the contents of my pre and textarea tags?](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.FAQ.html#q-preserve)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Jostein, that looks amazing, ahh why didn't I think of HAML????!!!! Yes i'm using HAML, that solved it. As a front end developer I knew how code and pre operated, and could not figure out WTF was going on. THank you so much for your insight